# Is there a known evaluation of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

Is there a known evaluation of $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^k}$$

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2Fk%5Ek%20from%201%20to%20infinity) says that it converges to $\approx 1.29129$.

Comment: [Sophomore's dream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream).

Comment: This is not so easy to find if you don't know what it's called.  IMHO it could do without the downvotes.

Comment: @David: You're right, but I think the downvotes are aimed at the poor formulation of the question.

Comment: @achillehui:But is there anyway to integrate that integral though?

Comment: @Gina, I don't think so. The sum itself converges very rapidly. Summing the first 60 terms or so already give you a number accurate to $> 100$ decimal places. There isn't too much point to find another way.